# French equivalent of "or anything (like that)"?

Tags: expressions

For example, if I want to say, in an informal context :

> It's not the best in the world or anything, but it's pretty good

What is the French equivalent of *"or anything"* here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I translate

> It's not the best in the world **or anything**, but it's pretty good

into

> Il/Ce n'est pas le meilleur du monde **ou quoi** , mais c'est/il est quand même très bon/doué

This *"ou quoi"* means the same as AbdouAbdou said when using *"ou quoi que ce soit"*.
 The full meaning is *"ou quoi que ce soit d'autre"*, = *"**or anything** else"*.

There is an explanation on [youtube](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQtwIwAmoVChMImND9zsmJxgIVR7UUCh2MegDu&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1wVpoGyaI30&ei=gYJ6VdiLKsfqUoz1gfAO&usg=AFQjCNEl7l7kIzbpGKCqYlpTHbi_NjkyYA&sig2=tlBmoqGNCzB5pQB6PsspNg).

---

This translation is for **an informal context**, as you requested.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I was guessing "ou quoi" as well, but I didn't know if it worked in a statement or only in a question.

Comment: @EM You can use it everywhere ! o/

Comment: You _can_. Still, I rarely hear it outside an interrogative context, but neither do I often hear "or anything," so that may actually be the best match.

Comment: @Chop I was totally exagerating with this *"everywhere"*. Just too much enthousiastic. :(

Comment: Plus one for recognizing that @AbdouAbdou was (at worst) on the right track.  IMO, he/she is well deserving of your admirable mention/credit and of the upvote I gave him/her earlier.  The consensus among native speakers seems to be that this notion is not translatable, but I have often heard and used (apparently incorrectly) "[… ou n'importe où, d'ailleurs …](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/%22ou%20n%27importe%20o%C3%B9,%20d%27ailleurs%20%22) to capture this notion.

Comment: Where are you from. I never heard this form, and if I were to hear that, I would ask where are you from. I doubt French people really use this form. Could be a local variant.

Comment: But where? It could be local. I didn't find an occurence with this expression on the internet.

Comment: Moi aussi. Mais je ne trouve quand même pas d’occurrence de ton expression, même si on comprend très bien ce que tu veux dire. Si tu trouves des occurrences, ça m'intéresse, j'aurais appris quelque chose. Pour moi, "ou quoi", qu'on peut utiliser à l'oral d'une façon très informelle, est plutôt utilisé quand il y a un choix.  T'es fou ou quoi? Tu veux la guerre ou quoi? Mais au centre d'une expression, je n'ai jamais vu ni entendu. ça me paraît un peu maladroit. Mais je coupe peut-être les cheveux en 4, excuse-moi ^^

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ce n'est pas forcément un choix, on ne désire pas savoir si la personne est folle, il s'agit de (re)situer le contexte de ce dont on parle, d'exprimer à son interlocuteur qu'il ne prend pas en compte tous les éléments à leur juste valeur... [Voilà une recherche google dans laquelle on peut en trouver quelques-uns.](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ou+quoi+mais%22&oq=%22ou+quoi+mais%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.494795.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.BYPoTtXuA4s)

Comment: Une alternative entre deux choses, et en fin de phrase, c'est bien ce que je vois dans ton lien.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Ici, si tu suis bien c'est effectivement une "alternative" et la fin de la proposition principale.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Cependant, dans mon lien, comme tu as pu le voir, la formulation *"Blahblah ou quoi mais"* est utilisée plusieurs fois.

Comment: "mais" introduit une proposition, le "ou quoi" est un enfin de proposition. Il est fou ou quoi? Mais....

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je ne vois pas où est le problème, *"ou quoi"* termine une proposition et *"mais"* en commence une autre. Cela correspond à tes remarques et à ma réponse

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the language level, you have different options

- *C'est pas franchement le meilleur du monde, ...* (very familiar)
- *C'est pas vraiment le meilleur du monde, ...* (familiar)
- *C'est loin d'être le meilleur du monde, ...* (a bit formal)
- *Ce n'est pas le meilleur du monde, loin de là, ...* (formal)
- *Ce n'est pas le meilleur du monde, loin s'en faut, ...* (very formal)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think "it's *not really* the best" is quite what I want to say. More like "it's not the best in the world - in case you were about to think that it was - but..."

Answer (score 2):

"*It's not the best in the world **in** anything*" would mean:

> Il n'est en **rien** le meilleur du monde .

Anything can be **rien** ,or  **jamais**, but the actual sentence refers to **anything** beside "the qualifier" which is **meilleur**. Either of these could work:

> Il n'est pas le meilleur du monde **ou rien de ça**.
>
> Il n'est pas le meilleur du monde **ou quoi que ce soit**.
>
> Il n'est pas le meilleur du monde **ou n'importe quoi**.

Comment: "Il n'est *en* rien le meilleur du monde" I'd rather say (for the first sentence).

Comment: "ou n'importe quoi" sounds like "or whatever", which is close to what I want. Does it have the same meaning I'm trying to convey, ie. "don't be tempted to think that it IS the best in the world"?

Comment: peut etre le dernier n'est pas inclut

Answer (score 2):

I just wouldn't translate "or anything" here :

> Ce n'est pas ce qui se fait de mieux dans le monde mais c'est quand même (très) bien.

The expression "or anything" is idiomatic English here; trying to translate it would result in an unnatural sentence.

You should also provide some context about what "it" is about.

Comment: Best answer for me ! Pourquoi traduire mot-à-mot une expression idiomatique.

Answer (score 1):

Only on the "*or anything*" issue:

> ...or anything
>  "*He didn't cry or scream or anything.*" "Il n'a
>   pas pleuré, ni crié, ni rien."
>
> [ *Collins Online English-French Dictionary* - "[or anything](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/-or-anything)" ]

---

> ...or anything
>   [usually with negative or in questions] informal Added as a general
>   reference to other things similar to the thing mentioned:
>
> 'Not that I know anything about Tibetan music or anything, but that is
>   what this reminds me of.'
>
> [ *ODO* - "[or anything](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/or-anything?q=or%20anything)" ]

It's the other similar thing, for emphasis. I believe Collins is spot on. It is "*ni rien*". Compared to this [other answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14063/3177), I believe nothing can be added to it and no substitute works.